# How to bracket the four corners of a letter?

Tags: math-mode, brackets

How do I make what is in this picture.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the “corner” symbols at a reduced size.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\corners}[1]{%
  \mathord{%
    \ooalign{%
      \raisebox{0.7ex}{${\scriptstyle\ulcorner}\!\phantom{#1}\!{\scriptstyle\urcorner}$}\cr
      \hfil$#1$\hfil\cr
      \raisebox{-0.7ex}{${\scriptstyle\llcorner}\!\phantom{#1}\!{\scriptstyle\lrcorner}$}\cr
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$\corners{x}$ $\corners{A}$ $\corners{y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The math symbols `\ulcorner`, `\llcorner`, `\urcorner`, `\lrcorner` can be used:

```
\def\incorners#1{\setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
   {\dimen0=\dp0 \advance\dimen0 by\ht0 \dimen1=\dp0
    \setbox1=\hbox{$\lrcorner$}\dimen2=.5\dp1 \advance\dimen1 by-\dimen2
    \lrcorners\ulcorner\llcorner 
    \kern-\dimen2 \box0 \kern-\dimen2
    \lrcorners\urcorner\lrcorner}%
}
\def\lrcorners#1#2{\lower\dimen1 \vbox to\dimen0{\hbox{$#1$}\vss\hbox{$#2$}}}

Test: \incorners{$x$}, \incorners{XYZ}.
```

Comment: Wow! it works for large enough font. But for small font the brackets touch making it look like a simple [ or ]

Comment: If you want to have smaller corners then try to `\scriptstyle` for printing these corners.

Answer (score 3):

The macro `\aframe{}` facilitates the brackets.  Here, I allow a scalefactor `\anglefrac` to determine the size of the angles.  Note, however, if `\anglefrac` is set too large, some vertical clipping of the top angles will occur.

The approach works across different math script-styles as well as different font base-sizes.  The parameter `\fboxrule` is obeyed for determining bracket thickness, whereas `\fboxsep` is redefined within `\aframe`.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{stackengine,scalerel,xcolor}
\newlength\angledim
\def\anglefrac{.3}
\newcommand\aframe[1]{%
  \mkern.5mu\ThisStyle{
  \fboxsep=1\LMpt
  \setstackgap{L}{0pt}
  \setbox0=\hbox{$\SavedStyle\vphantom{Xg}#1$}
  \setlength\angledim{\anglefrac\ht0}
  \savestack\z{\copy0}
  \Longstack{%
  \z{}
  \raisebox{\angledim}{%
  \textcolor{white}{\ht0=\dimexpr\ht0-2\angledim\relax
                  \fbox{\phantom{\copy0}}}}
  \textcolor{white}{\fbox{\kern-\angledim\phantom\z\kern-\angledim}}
  \fbox{\phantom\z}
}}\mkern.5mu}
\begin{document} 
$ x\aframe{Q}\aframe{x}
 \scriptstyle
 x\aframe{Q}\aframe{x}
 \scriptscriptstyle
 x\aframe{Q}\aframe{x}$

\LARGE$ x\aframe{Q}\aframe{x}
 \scriptstyle
 x\aframe{Q}\aframe{x}$
\end{document}
```

[image]